# Using get_query_var() from a plugin

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm trying to do a redirect feature in a plugin and i have an issue. First, the code:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    add_rewrite_rule( 'go/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?redirect_to=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_tag( "%redirect_to%", '([^&]+)' );`
} );
```

Ok, so, the rule is set. The tag is set. If i'm using `get_query_var('redirect_to')` inside of `functions.php` (or anywhere in the theme actually) it works, but if i'm trying to use the same query var from the plugin files, it silently fails. And since it's a plugin, there is no way to ask users to edit their themes :)

Things i did:

- i'm using it inside of `init` hook set as priority 999
- it works if i use `wp_head` instead of `init`, but this way i can't do the redirect anymore
- i flushed rewrite rules

So, my question is: how do i use the damn `get_query_var('redirect_to')` inside of my plugin files?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that `init` is too early, as the `query_vars` haven't been set yet. Have you tried hooking into the `parse_query` action?

Comment: yes! this works. please add is as a post to be able to select it as the correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into `parse_query` instead:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'go/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?redirect_to=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_tag( "%redirect_to%", '([^&]+)' );`
} );
```

Reason: `init` is too early, query_vars haven't been set yet. `wp_head` is too late, no can redirect at that point.

Comment: Actually rewrite rules should be added on init. But `parse_query` is the right hook to to retreive the bastard!

Comment: glad you got it worked out!